# How do I determine which c++ redistributables my program needs to run?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is it possible that I need to install both a vcredist for vs2012 AND for vs2010?

I just had an error where my app couldn't load a .dll and it suddenly started working after I did an unrelated installation, which prompted me to guess that it must have installed an older vcredist which fixed the issue. 
However I'm sure I'm using c++11 features.

Comment: Use [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com).

Comment: depends only told me about missing 110.dlls. I know, weird. But it did.

Comment: This can happen if your program depends on third party libraries built with another Visual Studio version.

Comment: c++ third party libs? Hm I'm fairly sure I'm not using any other c++ dlls, the product is pretty much c# only, but I realize that "pretty much" doesn't cut it. I'll look into it. But in general, I assumed that the 2012 vcredist would include all the functionality of older vcredist. That is not actually true?

Comment: I don't know, perhaps 110 missing dlls is the real problem and the content of your question is but an insignificant consequence of that problem. It's hard to know without knowing what these 110 dlls are.

Comment: With those I just meant msvcp110.dll and msvcr110.dll

Comment: How can we be expected to know which runtime your program depends on?

Comment: David, you are not expected to know that. I asked whether it is possible that despite having installed vcredist2012, my c++ program could still need vcredist2010 in addition.

Comment: I stopped developing for Windows some time ago with vs2010. So I can only tell for the "old days". The 2010 redist needed the old 2005 redist to install as it didn't bring the old msvc*.dll's. Maybe MS changed that, but I don't think so, because it would counteract the goal of the redist, update only that part of the OS which is necessary.

Comment: depends development seems to be stopped and it doesn't work very well anymore on modern systems (win10 for instance..) but you can try this "Dependencies" tool from lucasg on github, which seems to do its job: https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Deployment is a job on its own. And I hate it, I hate the way you have to write installations on Windows. …So that feel better now…

You only need one vcredist. The one the linker decided to link your program to. If you have the "Windows SDK's" installed you will find the actual redist in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x86
```

If you install all updates including the not important ones, Microsoft will update your redist in that folder!

Maybe you have an executable, which do not want to run, you need the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com). A tool, so usefully that Microsoft had to remove it from the Visual Studio. Download the program and open your exe in it. You do not need to understand what really happen. As long as no Dialog comes up during opening, everything is okay, even if there are exclamation marks in the bottom window. If a Dialog comes up with something like "Could not resolve" than look in the bottom window. Usually there is now in the lower window something like 
"msvcr.dll" or "msvcr100.dll" or "msvcr110.dll".
If it includes an "d" before the extension like "msvcr100d.dll" the executable was compiled in debug mode and your journey ends on a system without installed compiler. If not, the name is telling you which vcredist you need:

msvcr100 = VS 2010 redist [(32bit)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a7b7a05e-6de6-4d3a-a423-37bf0912db84&displayLang=de)   [(64bit)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=BD512D9E-43C8-4655-81BF-9350143D5867&displaylang=de)

msvcr110 = VS 2012 redist [(32/64bit?)](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

sometimes it is not msvcr but it always starts with "ms". Of course the program will tell you every dll which is missing, not only microsofts and which command in the dll is used. This is sometimes extremely useful.
You have to do that with every dll in the folder of your executable as they can also have unresolveable dependencies.
Back to your first question. Your program can only link to msvcr100 or msvcr110, not to both, that is the reason you only need one vcredist per executable. 
As mentioned in a commentary, A third party DLL can be guilty of using a different msvcp version. So yeah, you have to search all DLL's you use and you have to install both vcredist some times.

PS: There are always at least two of them, msvcr and msvcp.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible for a program to use a 3rd-party DLL that links to version X of the msvcrt and the program(exe) itself links to version Y of the msvcrt? In which case, to start the program, you'd need both redistributables.

Comment: Martin, first you say that a program can only link against one, but then you say a third party dll can make it necessary to have both. It's not clear to me how it's possible that on the one hand only one is required, but on the other hand both need to be there. I also have several SDKs installed in `C:\Program Files(x86)\[etc..]`, but 2 things: First, only the 7.0A even has a Bootstrapper\packages folder and secondly the vcredist that is in there, is only a vs2010 vcredist. So it can't possibly be enough because I *am* using c++11 features.

Comment: Sorry for that, let me clarify that. If you have a single exe, with no dependencies to any DLL's other than system DLL's, only one msvcr version is needed, as the linker links that exe to only one version. If the executable late binds a custom DLL which is not the result of the same compile process, this DLL could be linked against another version of the redist's. In that case, you have to install both redists. With the SDK you are right. Looking through my folders only 7.0A has the folder, sorry for that.

Comment: So there is no equivalent folder where a vs2012 vcredist would be kept updated through windows updates? I think I see what my problem probably was. I'm using the jvm.dll through LoadLibrary(), and I found this article: http://www.duckware.com/tech/java6msvcr71.html

Comment: That woudn't help you anyway. An examble. If you had install your system after 2010 and installed only new compiler and software, the msvcr71.dll would be still missing as it is a part of the 2008 package. An update vs2012 vcredist does not include it. For that, you have to install that special old vcredist. I have not installed the 2012 VS as I currently do not start new development on windows base, so I can not say if there is a folder with the redist. I would assume there is, and if in the VS 2012 folder is a redist, it will be updated by windows update. Uh end of comment length.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to know which runtimes are needed, you can try using the "Dependencies" tool from lucasg on github (https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) which works on modern systems like win10.

You'll just have to look for `MsVcR##.dll` o `VcRuntime###.dll` (where # stands for a digit) in the dependency tree..

HTH

PS: The old-and-faithful "dependency walker" we've been using for years seems to be unable to handle the way newer OS handle delayed dependencies, marking them as "missing", while they are not missing, just delay loaded in a way it doesn't know...

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem as follows (on Windows 7):

1. I tried to load the library and it failed showing "The application failed to start because its side by side information is incorrect."
2. I opened "Computer management" window: Start -> right click on Computer->Manage.
3. In the "Computer management" window I selected "Event Viewer"->"Windows logs"->"Application".
4. The log corresponding to the error said that a DLL for a certain version of Microsoft.VC90.CRT was not found. In my case the version was 9.0.30729.6161 and the search for it in Google revealed I needed to install an "unusual" version of redistributables from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368).

The dependency walker did not help for me (it only confused me by reporting unnecessary dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

If your OS is Vista or later (not XP), use the built-in SxStrace.exe to generate a log of which DLL's are being loaded and what module requires them.  It will clearly show you if multiple CRT DLL versions are being loaded, and for what DLL's (3rd party or no).

The VS2012 redistributable is put into, e.g. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\redist".

-- David